# Data bind loop knockout js , if I want to show only 2 names at a time from a list

Tags: css, html, knockout.js

I want to show only first 2 things which are present in an array instead of all , Can you help me in correcting the code of knoctout js .

```
<div class="slide">
    <ul data-bind="foreach:EventBE.WhoElseAttends">
           <li >
               <span data-bind="text:FirstName"></span> 
               <span data-bind="text:LastName"></span>
               <span data-bind="text:Company"></span>
           </li>
    </ul>                  
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using `foreach`?

Comment: see my code and tell what should i do

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computed.

```
var EventBE = {
    WhoElseAttends : ko.observableArray([
        { FirstName : "a", LastName : "b", Company : "c" },
        { FirstName : "b", LastName : "c", Company : "d" },
        { FirstName : "c", LastName : "d", Company : "e" }
    ]),
    AttendsComputed : ko.computed(function() {
        var attendees = EventBE.WhoElseAttends();

        return attendees.slice(0, 2);
    });
};
```

In your HTML

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:EventBE.AttendsComputed">
```